# Get text from txt file jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked around at many questions, trying to mimic the code. However, I cannot get mine to work. When I run it, nothing is inserted to the div as text. It is just empty. Here is my code:

```
case 2:
    $("#cont").fadeOut(500, function() {

    $.get('about.txt', function(data) {
        $("#cont").html(data).fadeIn(500);
        }, 'text')});


    $("#header").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $("#header").html("About").fadeIn(500);
    });
    break;
```

***Works in Firefox but not Chrome!***

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: There are none. I tried in Firefox and it is working fine... This is a local file since I am testing quickly. Is there issues with reading it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is a local file since I am testing quickly. Is there issues with reading it that way?

Some browser apply security settings that prohibit the use of `file:///` URLs in AJAX calls, so yes this is exactly what the problem is. Which is unfortunate, but necessary.

Personally, I have PHP 5.4 installed on my computer, and I can use it as a development server just fine to get around this problem.